# Get user input from input field in react similar to getElementById in react native using props

Tags: react-native, state, react-props

I am doing a loan calculation app and i run into the trouble since i am new to react native and previously i have been manipulating the DOM using querySelector or getElementById functions. However this does not work in react, and i am using state to store the value from the user, but i just can't seem to get it right, What am i doing wrong?

I've inserted the calculation element that is later rendered in app.js. All elements are showing up with no error, but the problem is to get user input data and then be able to use that data and do calculations.

> Here is my Class

```
class LanKalkylElement extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        loanAmount: 20000,
        loanInterest: 2.5,
        loanYear: 10,
    };
  }

  changeAmount(loanAmount) {
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        loanAmount: parseFloat(loanAmount),
      };
    });
  }

  changeInterest(loanInterest) {
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        loanInterest: parseFloat(loanInterest),
      };
    });
  }

  changeYear(loanYear) {
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        loanYear: parseFloat(loanYear),
      };
    });
  }

calcButton() {
    Alert.alert(this.props.loanAmount);
}

buttonHomeFunc() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Start');
}

render() {
    const {loanAmount, loanInterest, loanYear} = this.state;
    return(
        <View  style={styles.contentStyle}>

            <Text style={styles.text}> Lånebelopp </Text>
            <TextInput  style={styles.numericInput}
                        onBlur={Keyboard.dismiss}
                        keyboardType={'numeric'}
                        value={loanAmount}
                        onValueChange={this.changeAmount.bind(this)} />

            <Text style={styles.text}> Ränta </Text>
            <TextInput  style={styles.numericInput}
                        onBlur={Keyboard.dismiss}
                        keyboardType={'numeric'}
                        value={loanInterest}
                        onValueChange={this.changeInterest.bind(this)} />

            <Text style={styles.text}> Antal år: {String(loanYear)}</Text>
            <Slider step={1}
                    maximumValue={15}
                    value={loanYear}
                    onValueChange={this.changeYear.bind(this)} />

            <Button title='Kalkylera' onPress={() => this.calcButton()}/>
            <Text style={styles.textResult}>Total summa att återbetala:</Text>
            <Text style={styles.textResult}>varav räntekostnad:</Text>
            <Button title='Tillbaka' onPress={() => this.buttonHomeFunc()}/>

        </View>   
    )
}
}
export default withNavigation(LanKalkylElement);
```

Comment: Sorry what's the issue exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a user changes a value in a text input, onValueChange is called. You have bound this prop to functions that modify the state for this component.

This means the value in the text input will always match the value in the state. Therefore, if you need to access the value in a text input you would simply retrieve it from the state, like this:

```
const loanAmount = this.state.loanAmount;
doSomethingWithLoanAmount(loanAmount);
```

Comment: Thanks for putting it in a simple context, managed to solve it with your input :)